# Best Way to Access OpenStack CLI from Windows?

Tags: command-line-interface, openstack

I have a Windows 7 workstation and am given Ming64 to access the OpenStack CLI (blade farm) through SSL using a cert.

I've got to think there's a better way.  This is quite a secure environment and I can't install any non-approved software.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you install Python on the Windows machine? If you can, try to `pip install` the OpenStack client:

```
pip install python-openstackclient
```